# Как, используя Shell, вычислить суммарный объем ТОЛЬКО файлов, без подкаталогов, в каталоге linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Фрагмент bash скрипта, который вычисляет объем файлов вместе с вложенными в каталог подкаталогами.
Как изменить данный код так, чтобы ответом был общий размер ТОЛЬКО файлов (в килобайтах)?

```
subdirectory_size=$(du -sh | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo 3. Размер: $subdirectory_size КБ
```

Comment: `du -ck $(find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f) | tail -n 1`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это решило проблему

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

```sh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0|du --files0-from=- -ck|tail -1
```

Вернёт `0       total`, если в текущем каталоге нет регулярных файлов.
Команда `du $(find ...)`, в этом случае, продолжит подсчёт по всем подкаталогам.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой алиас для этого, попробуйте

```
alias cdu='du -ck $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f)|tail -1'
```